# Android itext, class not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, itext

I have eclipse ADT and testing basic itext createPdf example. I have added itextg-5.5.9.jar for android. When I run the app the logcat `enter code here`shows :

```
10-09 17:13:18.398: E/dalvikvm(306): Could not find class      com.itextpdf.text.Document', referenced from method in.refort.MarkList.MarkListActivity.createPdf
```

The app is working but when I call function createPdf(), it obviously crashes due to the above exception.

To pinpoint the problem I have removed everything from createPdf and I am left with only one statement which creates instance of Document class.

```
private void createPdf()
{   
 Document document = new Document();
 }
```

which is the root cause of the problem and produces the same error.

I have imported com.itextpdf.text.Document; so compiler does not complain.

Tested similar java desktop application with normal itext (instead of itextg) which works well giving me hello.pdf

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I can image many causes:

- A Wrong Jar.. Try to use ItextG as recommended by IText for android:
  [link](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android)
- Copy Jar manually to libs directory not via Wizard
- Updating ADT

Beside that, since supporting Eclipse has been stopped by Google. It's highly recommended to migrate your code to Android Studio.

Comment: I have used itextG as already mentioned in my question. Also I have copied itextG manually. So now will update ADT and run again. Will shift to Android Studio later. Tnx Maher.